# Mystery! One of my .xml layout resources is just not being detected! What's going on?

Tags: android, listview, layout, resources

**UPDATE: Solved, i'm an idiot, thank you everyone!**

> Okay little bit weird..
>   I just created a layout file for list items, I can see it there now, in my res/layout folder. It's called itemListBudget.xml. Inside i've declare two id's, catItem and budgetAmount as you can see here: http://pastebin.com/ZV0wr9L0 (it'll only take a second to look at)
>
> So now i'm just trying to bind data from my sqlite table to my list! Here's my method:

```
//
private static int[] TO = { R.id.catItem, R.id.budgetAmount, };
private void showBudgetOutcome(Cursor cursor) {
    //Set up data binding 
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.itemListBudget, cursor, FROM, TO,);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

> Now i'm being told that **R.id.catItem cannot be resolved**. **R.id.budgetAmount cannot be resolved** and of course **R.layout.itemListBudget cannot be resolved**. Why on earth could this be?
>
> I also have an error message saying my **setListAdapter(adapter) is undefined**, but i think that's caused by the problem above right?

Comment: add import android.R; at the start of the file to import R

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so are you sure Eclipse isn't just throwing a funny turn? If I leave my project open when I close eclipse, when I open it again (and eclipse re-opens the project) it will often give me all sorts of spurious errors.

Comment: Thanks i've tried importing .R; too but it hasn't seemed to have made a difference :/ And yeah i thought eclipse was just playing up but shutting it down and re-opening it hasn't changed anything hmmm

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: Try building with Ant, Eclipse's plugin jams sometimes

Comment: i've tried right clicking the project, Source>Clean up.. (that should do it right?) Still no change. and i opened and closed the project properly.. I've taken a screenshot of the resource to prove its there to you guys and myself haha. I'm flummoxed.

Comment: Ant'll be a plugin right? Thanks i'll give it a go. Ps new to all this, there's alot of Ant related stuff around, what should i be looking for? sorry and thanks!

Comment: @Holly, No, not source -> Clean up, you want project -> clean

Comment: Oh my god thanks for pointing me towards the clean, but when i cleaned it my R.java vanished! :O

Comment: If R.Java doesn't get generated, that means there's a problem with your xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in Eclipse try to do clean on the project and force it to rebuild R.java

Your layout CAN'T have capital letters in the file name !!!
its [a-z0-9_.]

Comment: Thanks, Sorry could you tell me how i would force it to rebuild R.java?

Comment: Just clean the project.  R is generated each time you compile.

Comment: Rebuilt it, and i looked at R.java and it doesn't seem to be updated with the new .xml! hrm

Comment: OHHHH i thought they just had to start with a lowercase. Gosh i'm a dumb sh*t thank you! Very much! haha

Answer (score 0):

Are you import android.R in your java class? If so, don't, that's the problem.

Comment: I'm not importing android.R anywhere, but thanks for the suggestion. I'm really stumped here.